# Kotlin idiomatic way to forward property from different class

Tags: generics, kotlin, reflection, delegates

As in example:

```
class A {    
    var value: String
    get() = "value"
    set(value) { println(value) }
}

class B {
    val a = A()
    var value = a.value
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    B().value = "new value"
}
```

`B.value` is only initialized with `A.value.get`, so of course `A.value.set` is not called during assignment in the `main` function, and thus doesn't print the message to console.

What I look for is syntax that would allow to forward both `get` and `set` functions to new variable based on different object's property of the same type.

I managed to implement such delegate, but it relies on kotlin-reflect library (invoking `getter` and `setter`) and I would like to avoid that:

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty
import kotlin.reflect.KMutableProperty

class Forward<T> (private val originalProperty: KProperty<T>){
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return originalProperty.getter.call()
    }
}

class ForwardMutable<T> (private val originalProperty: KMutableProperty<T>){
    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        originalProperty.setter.call(value)
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return originalProperty.getter.call()
    }
}

fun <T> forward(originalProperty: KProperty<T>) = Forward(originalProperty)
fun <T> forward(originalProperty: KMutableProperty<T>) = ForwardMutable(originalProperty)

class A {
    var value: String
        get() = "value"
        set(value) { println(value) }
}

class B {
    val a = A()
    var value by forward(a::value)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    B().value = "new value" // calls A.value.setter
}
```

Isn't there a build-in delegate for such purpose? If not, how can I avoid `kotlin-reflect` dependency?

Answer (score 0):

If `thisRef` has to be as generic as `Any` then I don't think you can access its properties without reflection.

If you are willing to introduce additional interfaces, you could probably do something along these lines: (there is still an import dependency on `kotlin.reflect`, but that is required by the `Delegate` API)

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

interface HasA<T> {
    val a: ValueAccessor<T>
}

interface ValueAccessor<T> {
    var value: T
}

class ForwardMutable<T> {
    operator fun setValue(thisRef: HasA<T>, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        thisRef.a.value = value
    }

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: HasA<T>, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return thisRef.a.value
    }
}

class A : ValueAccessor<String> {
    override var value: String = "value"
}

class B : HasA<String> {
    override val a = A()
    var value by ForwardMutable<String>()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b = B()
    b.value = "new value" // calls A.value.setter
    print(b.value)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for more lightweight approach. Defining interfaces (basically contracts) is too much for (seems not so) simple property access. In worst case scenario I could just write `var value: String get() = a.value; set(value) {a.value = value}`, but I wanted to generalize that with delegation.

Comment: Well there are only two ways to access a property generically without compilation errors - a. thru an interface exposing that property; b. thru reflection.  Pick your poison. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding something, but, if you are able to extract an interface of the variables you want to delegate to the inner instance, then why not just use delegates?

```
interface SomethingWithValues{
    var value: String
    var value2: String
    var value3: String
}

class A : SomethingWithValues{
    override var value: String = "value"
        set(value) {print(value)}
    override var value2: String = "value2"
        set(value) {print(value)}
    override var value3: String = "value3"
        set(value) {print(value)}
}

class B(val a:A = A()): SomethingWithValues by a

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val b = B()
    b.value = "new value"
    b.value2 = "new value2"
    b.value3 = "new value3"
}
```

Comment: That's an option. But unfortunately it won't work if: 1. I don't own class `A`. 2. I want to decorate property with different name.

Comment: Okay, problem 1 is unavoidable, but problem 2... I quite like your `ForwardMutable` solution. Why no reflection? I mean can you conceive of solving this problem without reflection in any language? Even if the kotlin library provided this type of property delegate out of the box, I am pretty sure it would be using reflection.

Comment: There are many reasons not to use reflection. In Kotlin it's kind of statically bound to delegated properties, so it's not that bad. But since Kotlin is JVM language (basically parsed to Java), it's possible (sometimes) to replace dynamic code with static one. For example Kotlin could have syntax `var value: String watch a::value` and it would generate setter and getter java code, no reflection involved, but that's just my dreaming at this point.

Comment: Ya, fair point, I had forgotten that this was all aiming at syntactic sugar for avoiding writing some of the syntactic sugar kotlin already provides ;)

Comment: @xinaiz I think your existing implementation is good lacking a language construct, and if what you are doing is trying to suggest a compile time construct, then maybe raise it in jetbrains kotlin forums?